# How to access an Interface Builder UILabel with code?

Tags: swift, uilabel, interface-builder, iboutlet

There's a UILabel in Interface Builder without a custom class or tag. I need to programmatically change the y coordinate of this UILabel. I know I can reference the UILabel by setting the tag and using viewWithTag. But how do I do it with IBOutlet? Can I set the custom class in IB and then somehow reference the custom class and assign it to an IBOutlet var?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the label to have a custom class for this. Add an outlet to the owning class (typically, the view controller):

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel
```

Then in the storyboard, drag from the outlet in the connections inspector over to the label in interface builder.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I have a storyboard as Main Interface is blank. Can't I do something with the empty circle that formed to the left of the IBOutlet var?

Comment: What is the name of the file you are editing, is it a .xib or a .storyboard? Can you add a screenshot of interface builder to your question?

Comment: The empty circle is what you drag from to make the connection, if you can see that then hopefully things are wired up properly, but there are a number of different configurations of what you see in interface builder and what you're editing so it's hard to answer without a bit more detail from you